# American citizen traveling back to US with foreign friend

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, travel-companions

I am a US citizen living abroad. Soon I will return to the US on vacation, but I will be taking a friend with me who is not a US citizen.

There's no issues with visas, rather my question is in regards to the procedure during customs / immigration. Am I allowed to take them with me in the line for US citizens or will they need to separately go through the line designated for visitors?

Edit: Friend is a citizen of a country within the VWP.

Comment: What is your friend's nationality, and where are you entering the US? VWP nationals often go in the same queue as US citizens nowadays

Comment: @Crazydre Friend is a citizen of a country within the VWP. Thanks for your information!

Comment: And where are you entering (i.e. at what Airport and terminal)? I know the exact rules at several

Comment: @Crazydre Guam. AB Won Pat International.

Comment: Ohhh, that's different. See, in major mainland Airports there are kiosks used both by US, Canadian and VWP citizens as well as permanent residents (the exact rules vary from Airport to Airport) but the overseas territories don't have them, so I'd imagine it's the "old" system. In that case, you could go through the non-US line, as you have an absolute, undisputable right to enter your own country

Comment: @Crazydre Ah, understood. Thanks for your responses on this question.

Comment: There was an article a while back that Guam was planning to have APC installed at the airport in August of this year.  But haven't seen anything to confirm if it happened or not.

Comment: You're both adults, I presume. Why can't you go through separately? You can meet up at baggage claim or outside arrivals.

Comment: I've been told on a few occasions to go to the US citizens line with my non-US-citizen traveling companions.  I've never been told to split up, or that we would have to go together to the non-US line.  Just ask when you get there; try to ask a CBP officer rather than a security person.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas they obviously *can* go through separately, but why would they want to when there's no need?

Comment: I should clarify my comment.  I *have* been told to split up, by airport security personnel who were directing US and non-US citizens to the appropriate line.  I ignored them, and when I got to the counter, I asked the CBP officer about their instructions, and the officer said, "they don't know what they're talking about."  So the airport security personnel do not necessarily receive very detailed training about the rules concerning the various lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the arrival airport, and whether your friend have visited the USA after 2008.

If you fly into one of the airports which has [Automated Passport Control](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc) (the link lists all them and it seems like every major airport is there), then YES, your friend can use this line **if he visited the USA after 2008**:

> Who Is Eligible to Use APC?
>
> U.S. and Canadian passport holders and international visitors from
>   Visa Waiver Program countries are eligible to use APC kiosks.  Visa
>   Waiver Program visitors must have Electronic System for Travel
>   Authorizations (ESTA) approval prior to travel and have visited the
>   United States on at least one occasion after 2008.

If you don't fly to an airport with APC, you need to ask the person managing the citizen/noncitizen line (some small airports don't even separate them). CBP officers in "US citizen" line are certainly capable to process non-citizens, including even people with visitor visas.

Comment: At Miami VWP nationals don't even need to have previous entries

Comment: Thank you for this response, this is really good information! Unfortunately, the airport I'm going (Guam) was not listed in this article.

Comment: Are you traveling as kind-of-family, filing up only one custom declaration? Or each of you will have your own custom declaration?

Comment: @Crazydre that's the official requirement from CBP, which seems to be current. Personally I went through the same passport control agent with my sister (who had a visa, so she wasn't even VWP), but it was a very small arrival at cruise terminal.

Comment: @GeorgeY. That is not the universal truth, as it is a matter of Airport policy (and not what the machines are capable of). Philadelphia only lets US citizens and Permanent residents use APC, whereas at JFK and Toronto even B1/B2 visa holders can

Comment: @Crazydre but the machines aren't all the same.  I suspect very strongly that the airport policy is dictated by the machines' software and little else.

Comment: @phoog: those machines are installed and operated by CBP, not airport, so they shall be the same, right?

Comment: @GeorgeY. Are you sure they're installed by CBP?  Anyway, they're definitely *not* the same; there are two different types of machine visible in various online instruction videos.  Here's one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOWhxmdG8Aw; here's another: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZz165wNBa8.

Comment: That's what I've been told during Global Entry renewal interview at CBP, as I asked if those APC machines are the same as global entry. Was told they're also operated by CBP, but not the same, and collect different info.

Comment: @GeorgeY. well certainly the Orlando kiosks are branded for the airport and the San Francisco kiosks are branded for CBP, and the hardware is different.  The workflow and capabilities of the software appear to be different as well.  One thing that's certain is that the system is being constantly expanded and it seems likely that capabilities will be different in different places while that is underway, even if the intended end result is to have an identical experience everywhere.

Comment: i would also add that the "person managing the citizen/noncitizen line" is more likely to answer questions correctly if she or he is a CBP officer, if my experience is any guide.

Comment: @phoog I am Aware that the kiosks are of different models, but the fact remains that the Airports decide on their own who will be allowed to use them. In particular, some Airports (such as LAX TBIT) require VWP travellers to have a previous entry on their current passport since 2008, others (such as Dulles) simply a previous entry since 2008 (which is what the CBP Website states), and others (such as Miami) allow any VWP traveller. In practice, even where official Airport policy disqualify holders of a new passport from using the kiosks, one will likely have no Problems using them anyway

Comment: @Crazydre Do you have any evidence that these varying policies are in fact determined by airport authorities?  I have a hard time believing that airport authorities care very much one way or the other which travelers can use which lines.

Comment: @phoog I base it on the fact that at LAX TBIT, the loudspeaker explicitly said (Jan 2016) you have to have a previous entry on your current passport to use APC. However, I had a new passport and still did not get X:d by the kiosk, meaning it was perfectly able to process me. Also, when entering JFK T4 on my first-ever US visit, I (officially APC-ineligible) went to the kiosk, and although I got X:d, I was processed *much* faster than if I would've used the visitors line

Comment: @Crazydre but none of that supports your assertion that the policies are decided by the airports rather than by CBP, nor does it contradict my belief that the varying policies are in fact motivated by varying capabilities of the machines.  As to "previous entry on the same passport" I think that the "on the same passport" rule is generally assumed by people.  I've never seen it actually stated in an official source.  I assume the reason is that they want your prints to be in the system already, which they of course will be even if you entered with a different passport.

Comment: @phoog The "on the same passport" rule was explicitly stated by the loudspeakers at LAX TBIT, and I mailed LAX Prior to my trip and was told the same thing. Nevertheless, I was not X:d there with my new passport. At Dulles, however, I was recently told it does not apply, a previous entry at all is enough.

Comment: @Crazydre your experience at LAX just reinforces my belief that the rules are frequently misunderstood and therefore misstated.

Answer (score 6):

The currently accepted answer depends on automated passport control (APC), but not all airports have APC.

I have traveled to the US with non-US-citizen companions on many occasions, beginning around 15 years ago.  I've never used APC.

CBP officers have told me on several occasions to bring my non-US companions with me in the US citizens' line.  More recently, I have used the diplomats' line because I was traveling with someone who was entitled to use that line.

From these experiences, I infer that the basic principle is for people traveling together to approach passport control together, and to pick whichever line they think is best as long as at least one person in the group is eligible for that line.

This obviously might not apply to APC, since APC can't process all travelers.  Since I have never used APC, however, I am not in a position to offer any useful speculation about that.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend is definitely not allowed in the US line. Your better rights don't extend to them just because they're your friend.

The big question that I thought you'd be asking is; are you allowed in the non-US line with them?
This one is hazier.

Comment: Question is what nationality the friend has.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It wasn't a question of rights, it's just that the US line tends to be much faster and it'd be easier to coordinate if we didn't need to split and wait. I've seen people do this in front of me in the past, but I wasn't sure if it was acceptable to do.

Comment: US citizens have an absolute right to enter the US (including Guam), so OP can use the non-US line

Comment: @Crazydre That makes no sense.

Comment: @Crazydre If they have an absolute right of entry, I guess they can use the crew line and the diplomat line too then ;)

Comment: @Traveling This answer is incorrect.  I've been told in the past by CBP officers to bring my non-US companions with me in the US citizens' line.

Comment: @Berwyn while your comment points out an obvious logical flaw in Crazydre's reasoning, his conclusion is correct: a US citizen *can* go in the non-US line.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I was just commenting on the justification

Comment: Your "absolute right of entry" doesn't mean the officer can't say "you're in the wrong line, go to the back of that one" and make you wait, such as might happen if you tried to use a diplomat line without cause.

Comment: This is pretty unlikely to be correct. On the ground, the markings are much more likely to say "US passports" for one and "All passports" for the other (or, at least, that's how it works in the EU). Can you back up your claim that the non-US line actually is non-US only?

Comment: @ZachLipton I saw that exact thing happen the last time I entered the US at JFK.  The lines had been redesigned since the last time I'd been there and it was all rather confusing.  A family went to the diplomat desk from the front of a different line and we had to wait while the officer confirmed that they met none of the criteria for using the line (diplomat, A/G/NATO visas, active duty US military).  They were very confused by his questions.  Then he sent them away to find another desk.

Comment: @E.P. in fact the lines are typically labeled "visitors" or even "non-citizen visitors" or something more precise such as "visitors with visas except B-1/B-2." An image search will turn up some examples of this.  There's nothing explicit for newly arriving immigrants, for example, and nothing to help mixed groups decide what to do.